# Only load data binding feature in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to use Angular but it's a bit big (105k minified) and has a bunch of extra features I don't need. What I'm really looking for is just the databinding component. Can this library be used (maybe include a specific js) that has databinding only, or is it all or nothing?

Comment: That was the aim of Cute - https://github.com/timruffles/cute - but I'm not sure where that project now stands

Comment: Why do you want to make yourself believe that 105k is big? Do you perhaps believe that the 105k are downloaded with each and every request to your site?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need them now, later you will need some of them, I recommend you to use it. You can start using the data-binding and Ajax, is not all or nothing